# Nested bool should query not working with the minimum should match

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have the below query in which I want to get the search term `"Schwarz"` either in the name field or the message field.  The language must be Austrian and the status type should be equal to the provided list. I'm getting the following exception and I can't figure out why:

QueryParsingException[[my_test_index] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }]",

```
{
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "name": "Schwarz"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "message": "Schwarz"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "status_type": [
                                        "1",
                                        "2",
                                        "3",
                                        "4",
                                        "5",
                                        "6",
                                        "7"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "language": "Austrian"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            {
                "total": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is the query without the filter that still works:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "standard_analyzed_name": "Schwarz"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "standard_analyzed_message": "Schwarz"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "buzzsumo_status_type": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "3",
                  "4",
                  "5",
                  "6",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "language": "Austrian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total_interactions": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a filtered query you MUST have a filter part, which is not present here. I would suggest rewriting it like this, i.e. move the `terms` and `term` parts into the `filter` part:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "Schwarz"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "message": "Schwarz"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "status_type": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "3",
                  "4",
                  "5",
                  "6",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "language": "Austrian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

An alternative is to not use the `filtered` query and simply write it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "name": "Schwarz"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "message": "Schwarz"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "status_type": [
              "1",
              "2",
              "3",
              "4",
              "5",
              "6",
              "7"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "language": "Austrian"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't alter the structure of the query. I can only add to it. So you're saying i can just add a filter clause to it and it should be fine?

Comment: Yes, if you absolutely have to use a `filtered` query, you need a `filter` no matter what. Sad that you can't alter the structure, though, as you'll end up  with under-performing queries.

Comment: yea but it was working without one before. When  I added the nested bool thats what caused this to not work. I'm lost

Comment: Can you update your question with the working query you tried just before adding the nested bool?

Comment: I've added it to the question. Thankyou

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried again and your first query above works perfectly for me, i.e. no parse exception.